# To display next N numbers of prime numbers in java

Tags: java, methods, primes

I want to display next n numbers of prime numbers in java

so what i did is accepting the two inputs from user

he enters one number and then he enters the how many next prime numbers to be printed

but i am not getting any output there is no any error

i have created a `isprime()` which returns true or false if number is prime or not
and then in `main()` i created `count` variable to display howmany numbers to be printed

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class NprimeNumbers 
{
    public static boolean isprime(int num)
    {
        int count=0;

        int i;
        for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
        {
            if(num%i==0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count==2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter the number : ");
        int number=sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("How many prime numbers to print : ");
        int hmw=sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("------------------------------OUTPUT------------------------------");

        System.out.println();

        int count=0;           
                
                if(isprime(number))
                {
                    while(count==hmw)
                    {
                        System.out.print(number+",");
                    }
                    count++;
                    number++;
                }
            
            
        

    }
    
}
```

[image: Output]

The output should be 13,17,19,23,27

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: `while(count==hmw)` -> `while (count < hmw)`

Comment: Debugging is a useful skill. If you want to become a professional software developer, it will be a necessary skill. I suggest you use a debugger on your code. You can set a breakpoint, and then follow the program one step at a time. While doing that, you can monitor the variables.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @001 that didnt helped

Comment: Off topic: `if(count==2)  return true;  else  return false;` is the equivalent of `return count == 2;`.  You can also reduce the number of iterations of the loop in the `isPrime` method by using 2 as the initial value of `i`, going through the loop until `i` has reached the square root of `num`, and exiting the loop as soon as it its discovered `num` is not prime.  (But, leave `isPrime` as it is until after the bug is fixed.)

Comment: You also need to move `count++; number++;` to inside the loop. You will still have issues but that should get you started.

Comment: You should put the If check inside the loop otherwise this code won't work unless the first number inserted is prime.

Comment: What is the program supposed to do if a non-prime number is entered for `the number`?  What if, for example, I want  the 200 primes that follow 1296?

Comment: Another tool useful for debugging is pretend you are the computer.  You can use pen and paper for the memory. Create a table with these columns: `number`, `hmw`,  and `count`. Follow the code. Each time a variable is initialized or the value changed, put the current value in its column.  You will learn more if you do the debugging than if we do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an iterative *for-loop* to loop *hwm* times.

Within the *for-loop*, use a *while-loop* to check *isprime* with *number*.

As a note, in this case, the *while-loop* doesn't require any enclosing code block, since we'll increase *number* within the *isprime* call.
*[O'Reilly Media – Java, A Beginner's Guide, 5th Edition – "Loops with no Body"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-a-beginners/9780071606325/ch3lev1sec11.html)*.

```java
for (int count = 1; count <= hmw; count++) {
    while (!isprime(++number));
    System.out.print(number+",");
}
```

Here is the input and output.

```
Enter the number : 11
How many prime numbers to print : 5

------------------------------OUTPUT------------------------------

13,17,19,23,29,
```

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop should be on the outside of the `if` statement as you want it to run until the next 5 primes have been found. You only want to output the number and increase `count` if `isprime()` returns true. The `number` variable should be increased outside of the `if` statement since we need the next number regardless if the current one was a prime or not.

So it needs to look more like:

```
number++; // skip the number they entered
int count=0;                   
while (count < hmw) {
  if(isprime(number))
  {
    System.out.print(number+",");  
    count++;                        
  }
  number++;
}
```

As mentioned, your `isprime()` function is really inefficient. A slight fix would be to start at 2 and stop at num-1, returning false as soon as one of the numbers evenly divides into the candidate, as there's no reason to check any more numbers past that point. Only return true after you've determined that no numbers evenly divide into the candidate:

```
public static boolean isprime(int num)
{
    for(int i=2;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you go a step further, we can reduce the number of checks by using the square root of the candidate number, as described in the [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) section, as the upper bound of the for loop:

```
public static boolean isprime(int num)
{
    int upperBound = (int)Math.sqrt((double)num);
    for(int i=2;i<=upperBound;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is the structure and the condition of your while loop. Your condition is `count==hmw`. This is saying to execute the while loop only if the number of prime numbers they want to print is 0 (because you manually set count to 0). You need to make it `count <= hmw` (you could make it `count != hmw` but `<=` is better because if `count` somehow goes past `hmw` you are safe.

The incrementing of your while loop also has some issues. You increment outside the while loop with:

```
while(count==hmw)
   {
      System.out.print(number+",");
   }
   count++;
   number++;
```

You need to put the increments inside the loop:

```
while(count!=hmw)
   {
     System.out.print(number+",");
     count++;
     number++;
   }
```

Now this should be your output:

Enter the number : 3
How many prime numbers to print: 4

------------------------------OUTPUT------------------------------

```
3,4,5,6,
Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, if you want to print prime numbers only after the number is input by the user, you need to put your conditional statement in your while loop:

```
while(count<=hmw)
    {
        if(isprime(number)) {
          System.out.print(number + ",");
          count++;
        }
        number++;
     }
```

Now your output is perfect and looks like this:

Enter the number : 3
How many prime numbers to print: 4

------------------------------OUTPUT------------------------------

```
3,5,7,11,13,
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class NprimeNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number : ");
        int currentNumber = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("How many prime numbers to print : ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        printNPrimes(currentNumber, n);

        scan.close();
    }

    public static boolean isprime(int num) {
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= Math.sqrt(num); ++divisor) {
            if (num % divisor == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void printNPrimes(int currentNumber, int n) {
        int nextPrime = currentNumber + 1; // 12
        while (n > 0) {
            if (isprime(nextPrime)) {
                System.out.print(nextPrime + " ");
                --n;
                ++nextPrime;
            } else {
                ++nextPrime;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: could explain a bit how algo is trying to compute the answer or what can be its complexity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).